# Конструктор копирования С++

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, конструктор-копирования

```
Не получается сделать конструктор копирования.

const int MAX = 4;

class Queue
{
  int c;
  int *p;

public:

    Queue(); // по умолчанию
    Queue(int n){ // Конструктор с параметром
      if (n > MAX){
        c = 0;
        p = NULL;
      }else{
        c = n;
        p = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
          cout<<"Enter the element nr. "<<i<<" : ";
          cin >> p[i];
        }
      }
    }



    bool isEmpty(){
      if (c == 0)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }

    bool isFull(){
      if (c == MAX)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }

    bool add(int x){
      if (isFull()){
        cout<<"List is full. You can't add the element "<<x<<endl;
        return false;
      }else{
        for(int i=c;i>0;i--)
          p[i]=p[i-1];
        c++;
        p[0]=x;
        return true;
      }
    }

    int get(){
      if(!isEmpty()){
        c--;
        return p[c-1];

      }

    }

    void display(){
      if(isEmpty())
        cout<<"The queue is empty";
      else
        for(int i=0; i< c; i++)
          cout<<p[i]<<" ";
      cout<<endl;
    }

    Queue(const Queue &n){ // копирование

    }
};

int main(){
  Queue a(2); // с параметром
  a.display();
  a.add(10);
  a.display();
  a.add(6);
  a.display();
  a.add(100);
  a.display();
  int q1, q2;
  int x = a.get();
  cout<<"Your number is " << x << endl;
  a.display();
  x = a.get();
  cout<<"Your number is " << x << endl;
  a.display();


  //Queue q1 = a; copy
  //Queue(n);   // копий ????
  Queue z(); // по умолчанию
  // Копий
}
```

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Где ваши попытки? Что вы пробовали сделать? И нет, `Queue z(); ` - это не конструирование по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
Queue(const Queue& q):c(q.c),p(new int[q.c])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
        p[i] = q.p[i];
}
```

Comment: А как он вызывается?
        Queue (a); ???

Comment: Как он правильно вызывается в main ?

Comment: Странный вопрос... Просто когда вы создаете копию. `Queue a; ... Queue b = a;`

Comment: конструктор копирования вызывается при инициализации обьекта существующим обьектом, при передаче обьекта в функцию по значению, и при возврате обьекта через return